# How to overlay list item text color in specific region?

Tags: java, android, listview, colors, overlay

Let suppose we have the custom `ListView` which extends `onDraw()` method by drawing some rectangle in it.

```
class Listpicker extends ListView {
//..Some other methods here..//
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(glassPickerBitmap, null, glassRect, semiTransparrentPaint);
    }
}
```

The bitmap drawn represent some sort of glass which is rectangle with width equal to the width of listview and some height. What I want is when list item scrolls into this rectangle the color used for drawing text (not all item with background and etc.) would be changed into some another color. So, for example, when list item fits so that only half height of text fits into `glassPickerBitmap`, the outside part of list item should remain in its ordinal colors, and the part that is inside `glassPickerBitmap` should change its text color. List items are simple TextViews without any background.

How can be this achieved? Maybe any `ColorFilter`s assigned to the `Paint`? But where? `onDraw()` method of `Listview` is not even called when `ListView` is scrolled... Can be this done inside customized views, for example, that will be `ListView`'s items? Or may be some Color/Shader/do not know what else overlay can be used here, but **where**?

**EDIT (added image examples):**

Here is example of some crop from real-life app. There are 2 `ListView`s: one on the left side, other on the right. Glass is the grayed rectangle. Now, left list has **"United States Dollar"** currency selected. And I am scrolling right `ListView` in that way, that selection is somewhere between *USD* and *Afghan Afghani*. Now, what I want, is that *USD* currency in the left `ListView` would be drawn in red (exact color doesn't matter now, I will change it later to something meaningful) AND, in the same time, bottom part of *"United States Dollar"* and top part of *"Afghan Afghani"* in the right ListView would be drawn also in the same red color.

This color changing should be done in dynamic way - color should be changed only for the part of text that is under glass rectangle during scrolling of the list.

*OK, EUR and USD here are special currencies drawn with not standard cyan color. The question is about at least text with *white* color. But if it will be possible to change also cyan color it would be great.

[image: List example]

Comment: `View.setWillNotDraw` (boolean willNotDraw) should get `onDraw` called in the `ListView`.  Whether that will then enable you to achieve what you want is debatable.  Interesting question however.

Comment: @Prizoff can you provide two pictures (one of a regular item and the other of an item below the glass)?

Comment: @Prizoff cool, let me take a look

Comment: @Prizoff can you take a look at my answer?

Comment: @EvelioTarazona I will definitely take a loot at it, just not a long time later, now can't do any programming tools, have some other non-IT related problems. On the first look, it should work, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can tell in their implementation they use and update a fixed position in their `ListAdapter` so then they update the `View` that matches accordingly, which is to me the easiest and simpler way to do it, but you don't get the half-half colored text, which I think you still want :)

---

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jHvuBcL.png]

So here is probably one of the worst answers I've given, sorry about it, I'll probably revisit this or hope someone can point you to a better solution

You can see a blurry demo at:

http://telly.com/Y98DS5

The dirty way:

- Create a `Paint` with a proper `ColorMatrixColorFilter`, for the purposes of answering this I'm just desaturating, you'll have to figure out your 5x4 matrix for `ColorMatrix` to get the cyan your looking for. Also you will need some `Rect`s to define source and dest when drawing below.
- Create an off screen `Bitmap` and `Canvas` which you'll use to draw your list, that's done in `onSizeChanged` so we have proper view layout values, here you can start noticing the dirtiness as you will have to allocate a `Bitmap` as big as your `ListView` so you may get `OutOfMemoryException`.
- Override `draw` to use your off screen `Canvas` and let `ListView` draw to it, then you can draw the `Bitmap` to the given `Canvas` that will draw your list as usual, then draw just the part of that `Bitmap` which will be drawn differently using the `Paint` we defined before, you will get overdraw for those pixels.
- Finally draw your pre-fabricated glass `Bitmap`, I would recommend a n-patch (9-patch) so it scales and looks sharp across screens and densities, then you get more overdraw for those pixels.

The whole cake looks like:

```java
public class OverlayView extends ListView {
  private RectF mRect;
  private Rect mSrcRect;
  private Paint mPaint;

  private Canvas mCanvas;
  private Bitmap mBitmap;
  private float mY;
  private float mItemHeight;

  public OverlayView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    initOverlay();
  }

  public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    initOverlay();
  }

  public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    initOverlay();
  }

  private void initOverlay() {
    // DO NOT DO THIS use attrs
    final Resources res = getResources();
    mY = res.getDimension(R.dimen.overlay_y);
    mItemHeight = res.getDimension(R.dimen.item_height);
    //
    mRect = new RectF();
    mSrcRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();

    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
    mPaint.setColorFilter( new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix) );
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(mCanvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mSrcRect, mRect, mPaint);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mRect.set(0, mY, w, mY + mItemHeight);
    mRect.roundOut(mSrcRect);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
  }
}
```

So that said, I hope you end up with a cleaner solution, even if you don't get that half-half sexiness :)

Comment: Yup I use Max OS X precisely Maverixks

Comment: How about using `getDrawingCache()` instead of a separate bitmap ?

Comment: @S.D. yup you could use it as well, in fact does something similar to that, just comes with some extra quirks like the now deprecated max cache size, blank bitmaps, someone else could also use that drawing cache and as I remember you should only use it for software layers, in this case (not always) managing your own cache gives you control and some peace of mind: you know for sure it is your fault ;) anyways as I mentioned before this is dirty, and you should avoid it (worst salesman ever)

Comment: @EvelioTarazona It definitely works, thanks! First, I was trying to get it to wok by overriding onDraw() instead of draw(). But when I noticed that - things became much better. :)

Comment: @Prizoff my pleasure, last time I made one of those somebody said was "waiting for someone jumping out with an ax"

Answer (score 1):

First, keep a spare bitmap and canvas:

```
class Listpicker extends ListView {
    Bitmap bitmapForOnDraw = null;
    Canvas canvasForOnDraw = null;
```

Make sure it's the right size:

```
    @override
    protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        if (bitmapForOnDraw != null) bitmapForOnDraw.recycle();
        bitmapForOnDraw = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvasForOnDraw = new Canvas(bitmapForOnDraw);
    }
```

And when we come to drawing the list:

```
    @override
    protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas realCanvas) {
        // Put the list in place
        super.onDraw(realCanvas);

        // Now get the same again
        canvasForOnDraw.drawColor(0x00000000, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        super.onDraw(canvasForOnDraw);
        // But now change the colour of the white text
        canvasForOnDraw.drawColor(0xffff00ff, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

        // Copy the different colour text into the right place
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapForOnDraw, glassRect, glassRect overwritePaint);

        // finally, put the box on.
        canvas.drawBitmap(glassPickerBitmap, null, glassRect, semiTransparrentPaint);
    }
```